annotate ChIP-Seq peaks
I'm attempting to annotate several peaks with various approximations. Nevertheless, the expected results are not achieved.
T_S_1 is a Granges object which the following peaks:
# Load libraries

library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38.knownGene)
library(annotate)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
library(ChIPpeakAnno)
library(biomaRt)
library(dplyr)
library(annotables)
library(ChIPseeker)

T_S_1
GRanges object with 8 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames              ranges strand
         <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr4   49095333-49110821      *
  [2]     chr4   49118556-49123611      *
  [3]     chr4   49144334-49155031      *
  [4]     chr4   49632673-49637799      *
  [5]     chr4   49650080-49652369      *
  [6]     chr4   49709088-49711931      *
  [7]     chr4 190080573-190082795      *
  [8]     chr4 190177284-190180193      *

When annotating the peaks with this first approximation, the annotation column is correct as 6 of them are located in intergenic regions while the last two are located in  genetic region. However, when viewed in IGV it corresponds to  DUX4L4 and DUX4 and not LOC124900838.
txdb <- TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38.knownGene
annotated<-annotatePeak(T_S_1 , TxDb = txdb ,level = "gene" )
annotated1 <- as.data.frame(annotated)
annotated1$symbol<- getSYMBOL(annotated@anno$geneId , data = 'org.Hs.eg.db')
  seqnames     start       end                                   annotated1$annotation annotated1$geneId annotated1$symbol
1     chr4  49095333  49110821                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
2     chr4  49118556  49123611                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
3     chr4  49144334  49155031                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
4     chr4  49632673  49637799                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
5     chr4  49650080  49652369                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
6     chr4  49709088  49711931                                       Distal Intergenic             80157             CWH43
7     chr4 190080573 190082795 Exon (ENST00000566884.2/ENST00000566884.2, exon 1 of 1)         124900838      LOC124900838
8     chr4 190177284 190180193     Intron (ENST00000564366.2/100288687, intron 1 of 4)         124900838      LOC124900838


When the annotation is made with the EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, the following results are obtained:
ensembl.hs86.transcript <- transcripts(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
macs_peak_ensembl <- annotatePeakInBatch(T_S_1,
                                         AnnotationData = ensembl.hs86.transcript)

mart <- useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
                dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

macs_peak_ensembl <- addGeneIDs(annotatedPeak = macs_peak_ensembl, 
                                mart = mart,
                                feature_id_type = "ensembl_transcript_id",
                                IDs2Add = "hgnc_symbol")
macs_peak_ensembl$hgnc_symbol

[1] "CWH43"    ""         ""         "SNX18P25" "SNX18P25" "SNX18P25" "DUX4L4"   "DUX4"    

The last attempt didn't locate the peaks which are located in gene regions.
entrez <- annotated1$geneId

annotations_edb <- AnnotationDbi::select(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86,
                                         keys = entrez,
                                         columns = c("GENENAME"),
                                         keytype = "ENTREZID")

annotations_edb$ENTREZID <- as.character(annotations_edb$ENTREZID)

library(dplyr)

annotated_1%>% 
  left_join(annotations_edb, by=c("geneId"="ENTREZID"))

1     chr4  49095333  49110821                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
2     chr4  49118556  49123611                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
3     chr4  49144334  49155031                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
4     chr4  49632673  49637799                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
5     chr4  49650080  49652369                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
6     chr4  49709088  49711931                                       Distal Intergenic     80157      CWH43
7     chr4 190080573 190082795 Exon (ENST00000566884.2/ENST00000566884.2, exon 1 of 1) 124900838       <NA>
8     chr4 190177284 190180193     Intron (ENST00000564366.2/100288687, intron 1 of 4) 124900838       <NA>

